# Why has the market gone up while earnings got pummeled?

Tags: fundamentals

Earnings are down 42% while the market is flat over march. Why are people assuming total economic collapse is great? Are they assuming iPhones will enter a massive growth spurt just because people are staying home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is also residue of the 2008 financial crisis in Wall Street mentality: while there is an oversupply of liquidity through unprecedented government stimulus, unlike 2008 (and lessons learned from it) credit markets are well-oiled and healthy - that cash has to find its way somewhere and tech+pharma+financials are the beneficiaries; while hospitality+manufacturing (for good reason) are the underdogs.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a quant finance question, but i'll offer my 2c:

(a) interest rates are 1% lower than before, which increases the P/E multiples of all stocks

(b) it is assumed that earnings will bounce back strongly in 2021/22, especially if a vaccine is discovered

(c) the stock market is not very reflective of the main street economy any more - a significant percentage is big tech, which has been less affected by the stay-at-home restrictions of the pandemic.

Comment: A would take a long time. B doesnt explain why it's booming past the peak. C seems valid.